# Use Javascript to execute mysql queries

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm fairly new to PHP, JS and other web development oriented languages.

I have a big table that contains info directly retrieved from the database, at the end of each row I would like to add a button that deletes that line from the database.

Since there are a lot of entries in this table, I would like the button to call a function that erases the data concerning this row, but I can't seem to find how to even open a connection with the database from a script

```
<table>
<tr class="titles">
<td> <strong> column1 - id </strong> </td>
<td> <strong> column2 </strong> </td>
<td> <strong> column3 </strong> </td>
<td> <strong> column4 </strong> </td>
<td> <strong> etc... </strong> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>

<?php 
$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table';
$req = $bdd -> query($query);
$n = 0;
while ($data = $req -> fetch())
{
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $data['id'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['column2'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['column3'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['column4'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $data['column5'] . '</td>';

echo '<td> <button type="button" id="' . $data['id'] . '" onclick=\"delete_line(this.id);\" > Delete </button> </td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>

<script>
function delete_line(value) {
//*fucntion that execute the query : "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = value LIMIT 1;
}
</script>
```

Should the script modify a chunk of php and then call the same page (like a form) so it's executed??

Comment: Go read up on AJAX ...

Comment: Your client-side code would make an AJAX request to server-side code (likely a "page" of its own, but one that interacts via JSON instead of HTML).  This server-side code would perform your server-side actions (such as interacting with a database) and then respond back with some result to the client.

Comment: @David, what I'm struggling with is how to send the proper information with this AJAX request. Meaning I want to erase the contents of THAT line and that line alone. 
Without of course compromising the rest of the data to SQL injection and whatnot. 

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @FranciscoArandano: It looks like the value you want to send is the `id` value of the button being clicked.  It's certainly uncommon to use an `id` attribute for this, but not entirely invalid.  Your AJAX request would just need that value and the server-side code would use that value in the SQL query to identify the record to delete.